# Boot Process In Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machines, boot

I was Learning About the Booting Process...i got the exact procedure for Single and Multiboot Systems which is MBR -> BIOS -> POST -> GRUB -> INIT.

I wanted to know what is the exact booting Procedure in a Virtual machine and steps will be different in it's case as BIOS and POST are not required.

Comment: By virtual Machine i mean Booting over OS over OS as we do in VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about full virtualization, the boot process is the same as a physical machine: CPU initialization, BIOS/POST (memory, PCI initialization), MBR/GRUB, kernel+initrd loading, kernel boot, initrd execution, pivot root, service startup.

If you talk about containers, then the BIOS/POST, MBR/GRUB and the kernel are not performed.